# Programmatically fill UIImageView with UIImage and place in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimage, uicollectionviewcell

I have been trying to fill in a `UIImageView` with a `UIImage` (car system image). I have tried numerous solutions online but can not seem to have it fill the `UICollectionViewCell`, awkward spacing seen here:

[image]

I figured since the `UIView` is the size of the UICollectionViewCell as seen here:

[image]

It must be the image is not scaling to the view. So I modified the content mode to scale to fill of the image view when creating the cells for the collection view, then adding this image view into the collection view cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CarCell", for: indexPath)
    
    let carImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "car"))
    
    carImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    cell.addSubview(carImageView)
    
    return cell
    
}
```

This doesn't seem to have any effect (even when using .bottom for the content mode the image does not move), but looking in the view hierarchy it seems this is what should be fixing it.

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

Here is the storyboard:

[image]

Update:

I have added constraints to the image view with this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CarCell", for: indexPath)
    
    let carImage = UIImage(systemName: "car")
    
    let carImageView = UIImageView(image: carImage)
    carImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    
    cell.addSubview(carImageView)
    
    carImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor).isActive = true
    carImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    carImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    carImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    
    return cell
    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    let columns: CGFloat = 2
    
    let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let spaceBetweenCells = flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * (columns - 1)
    
    let adjustedWidth = collectionViewWidth - spaceBetweenCells
    
    let width: CGFloat = floor(adjustedWidth / columns)
    let height: CGFloat = width
    
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    
}
```

But it ends up shrinking the image view rather than growing it to the size of the cell:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you give the constraints to the image view?

Comment: @Suhail As I am generating the image view programmatically I have not given it any constraints yet. I am new to iOS and trying to learn constraints programmatically but can not seem to make it work in this case.

Comment: @Suhail I have added an update with constarints, but they are making the cells of the collection view smaller rather than scaling the image view up to the cell size

Answer (score 0):

Give constraint to your imageView is `zero` from all side of collectionView cell and set image content mode to `.scaleToFill` and than show the result.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried some solutions found online to programmatically set the imageView's constraints to 0 then set the content mode to .scaleToFill but I can't get it to work still

Comment: I have added an update to the question showing what happens when I add constraints, it shrinks the view rather than makes the image and image view larger

Answer (score 0):

I got you there. As I previously commented to show how you are giving constraints to image view, thus the error was there. There is a property called "translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints" which you need set while giving constraints to your views. You can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco).

Now, in your *cellForItemAt* you need to change:-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CarCell", for: indexPath)

let carImage = UIImage(systemName: "car")

let carImageView = UIImageView(image: carImage)
carImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill

carImageView.translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints = false

cell.addSubview(carImageView)

carImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
carImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
carImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
carImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

return cell

}
```

As you can notice I've also changed the constraint to give an idea about how you should give the constraints if you want to set the image size as exact as your cell. You should always access cell's content view when you're giving constraint not the cell.